# Annulus Homotopic to punctured plane

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I know a circle is homtopic to a punctured plane, and by the same reasoning, the aannulus must also be, as it a "step" in the homotopy (IE the annulus is a "stretched" circle). The only trouble is it is not clear how to construct the required $f,g$. Any thoughts?

Comment: You havve certainly tried something, at least for one of the two maps!... Can you tell us what?

Comment: Of course. For the instance of the circle and punctured plane, take $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus \{(0,0)\} \to S^1$ to be $\vec{x}\mapsto \vec{x}/||\vec{x}||$ is what I used in the instance of a circle. I figure I want to send the annulus  to the circle, by using the same f to show that the annulus is homotopic to the circle which is homotopic to the punctured plane

Comment: And what map did you use for the other direction?

Comment: Doesn't $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ suffice?

Comment: HA I just figured it out.
$$F((x,y),t)=\frac{t\sqrt{x^2+y^2} +(1-t)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} (x,y) $$ is a homotopy for the circle and annulus

Comment: Thank you! sometimes writing it out is all I need.

Comment: Please add an answer with what you found.

Comment: Ok! Let me know what you think. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fact, $S^1\simeq \mathbb{R}\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.
I want to show that $Y=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2| 1\leq x^2+y^2 \leq 2\} $ is homotopic to $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{(0,0)\}$. This can be done by showing $Y\simeq S^1$. Let $f:S^1\to Y$ send $(x,y)\to (x,y)$. For $(x,y)=z$, let $g(z)= \frac{z}{||z||}$. Clearly, $g\circ f$ is the identity on $S^1$ and is homotopic to the identity. For $f\circ g$ , define $F: Y\times I \to A $ by $F((z,t)= \frac{t||z||+ (1-t)}{||z||}z$
This map is continuous being the composition of continuous maps, and $F((x,y),0)=(f\circ g)(x,y)$ and $F((x,y),1)=(x,y)$. Hence, $f$ and $g$ are a homotopy equivalence from $Y$ to $S^1$.   Therefore, since $Y\simeq S^1$, $\implies Y\simeq \mathbb{R}\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: ¿Is $F$ well-defined? I've been trying to figure it out, but I don't see how can I prove that $\frac{t||z||+ (1-t)}{||z||}z \in Y$ $\forall (z,t) \in Y\times I$. Any help?